# Why is the value of a variable null inside a foreach loop container

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

I have a package that has a foreach file enumerator. Now I have a variable called `EmailTo` which is populated by an execute sql task outside the foreach container placed just before the loop container since i only need to run the execute sql task once. The variable `EmailTo` is being accessed by an send mail task inside the foreach container. When i inspect the breakpoint. I learned that the value of EmailTo variable is null inside the foreach container. Why is that?

Currently, I moved the execute sql task inside the foreach container to make it work because I have to present it to my boss but there is no point of moving the execute sql task inside the loop since i only have to fetch the email once.

What should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store an Execute SQL task Full ResultSet within a variable, it is stored as a Recordset.

A Recordset can be consumed once; if it is used by a Send Mail Task, then you cannot use it again.

You can use a Script Task to copy the Recordset into a DataTable object and store it within an SSIS object variable. Then you can use it multiple times.

**Additional Information**

- [SSIS 2012 - Variable empty on second script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293064/ssis-2012-variable-empty-on-second-script-execution/55293385#55293385)
- [I have two Foreach Loop,which hava same enumerated values.So how do I deal with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802442/i-have-two-foreach-loop-which-hava-same-enumerated-values-so-how-do-i-deal-with/56820847#56820847)

Comment: I used single. Is it still the same?

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio yes it is the same concept. But Make sure first that there is no problems with the Execute SQL Task configuration.